# generating random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose we have a coin that the probability of coming head is $p$. How can we generate a Bernoulli Random variable such a $X$ that the probability of both $0$ and $1$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, using this coin?

Comment: The usual trick is to toss the coin repeatedly in groups of $2$, until you get either $HT$ or $TH$.  Then we let $0=HT$ and $1=TH$.  of course, if $p$ is very near $0$ or $1$, it is likely to take a very long time to get an outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand lulu's answer.

Let's toss in group of two and record the outcome of the first appearance of two unequal dices, like $HT$ or $TH$. Let's suppose $p$ is the probability of getting heads and $q=1-p$. We introduce two random variables:

- $Z \in \{0,1\}$ be equal to $0$ if $HT$ comes first and $1$ if $TH$ comes first.
- Let us also introduce $N$ as the first time one of these double tosses comes with unequal outcomes.

Than:

$P(Z=0)=\sum_{n\ge1} P(Z=0, N=n)=\sum_{n\ge1} (p^2+q^2)^{n-1}pq=1/2$

And of course $P(Z=1)=1/2$

So we built indeed an even random variable from a biased dice, which is nice.

We can also avoid doing the summation if we believe in symmetry and normalization of course :) .